# Link in UITextView not working in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm using iOS 11 and Swift 4.

I am trying to programmatically generate a link inside a `UITextView`.

All the attributes work (i.e. color, size, range etc.) - but unfortunately, the link does not work. Can anybody tell me why?

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

// Setting the attributes
let linkAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.link: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
    ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Just click here to do stuff...")

// Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(5, 10))

self.textView.delegate = self
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Again, the link seems correct, but clicking it does not work.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the UITextView]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should enable `isSelectable` and disable `isEditable` for your text view.

```
textView.isSelectable = true
textView.isEditable = false
```

You can also set up these behaviors inside **Interface Builder** in the **Behavior** section of the text view's **Attributes inspector**:

[image: Interface Builder - Attributes inspector/Behavior]

Comment: Thank you! I was looking way too far. It was interesting that switching from Swift3 to Swift4 this 'editable' and 'selectable' property somehow got messed up inside storyboard (since before it was working fine). Better to do it programmatically - thanks!